# How to grep a word from a file and display only that word with its suffix not the whole line?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

How to grep a word from a file and display only that word with its suffix not the whole line?

Here's an explanation:

File includes the following: (xxxxxx is for random data)

```
xxxxxx
xxxxxx
word1 word2 word3 device324432 word5 word6
xxxxxx
xxxxxx
word1 word2 word3 device957438546443 word5 word6
xxxxxx
word1 word2 word3 device11128546443 word5 word6
xxxxxx
```

If I grep for device I get the whole lines.
If I grep using -o I get only the word device (discarding the number)

What I need is to get the word until its end.

```
device324432
device957438546443
device11128546443
```

I used the `awk '{print $4}'` and that did the trick but I was wondering if there's a "grep" option for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine `-o` with an expression that matches the suffix.

```
grep -o 'device[0-9]*'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, this will display only one number after the word device.
So the output will be:

device3

device9

device1


So to display the entire thing I will need to add multiple arrays to the end of the word device.

i.e. device[0-9][0-9][0-9] ....

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The asterisk should handle the repetition.

Comment: it worked! .. 

I just had to use [0-9,a-z] as it contained letters as well :) 

Thank you Choroba for your help! .. I appreciate it.